# ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1 N N

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to import Postgresql .sql backup file into my local PostgreSQL data base. When it reaches copy command I am getting an error because \N is not read as null. import sample copy command

```
COPY address (id, city, company_name, country, created_date_time, email) FROM stdin;
```

> 1       \N      \N      \N      2018-07-05 16:03:41.717 abc@gmail.com

which gets me

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1       N      N

restore command:

```
psql -U xxxxx -d xxx -1 -f dump.sql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

Comment: What character are you using as a delimiter? The lack of a DELIMITER option to your COPY suggests that you're using tabs but are there really tabs in your file?

Comment: I didn't specify any delimiter. i am using the default one.

Comment: Is the data you're importing tab-delimited or does it use spaces?

Comment: Yes,It uses spaces

Comment: Fix the input to use tabs like [COPY is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) to expect or specify a space as the delimiter.

Comment: How do i specify delimeter as space in copy command

Comment: I linked to the COPY documentation above.